# How to bind model data in Spring Form Multiple Select

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Currently I am trying to bind model in spring form multiple select but I am getting error.

Product Model as Follow:

```
 @Entity
    public class Product implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3532377236419382983L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int productId;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JsonIgnore
        private List<CartItem> cartItemList;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "categoryId")
        @JsonIgnore
        private Category category;

        @ManyToMany
        @JsonIgnore
        @JoinTable(name="PRODUCT_SUBCATEGORY", 
                    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="productId")}, 
                    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="subCategoryId")})
        private List<SubCategory> subCategoryList;


        public List<SubCategory> getSubCategoryList() {
            return subCategoryList;
        }

        public void setSubCategoryList(List<SubCategory> subCategoryList) {
            this.subCategoryList = subCategoryList;
        }
Getter Setter...
```

SubCategory Model as follow:

```
@Entity
public class SubCategory implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7750738516036520962L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int subCategoryId;

    @NotEmpty(message = "The subcategory name must not be empty")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Minimum 3 to 20 characters allowed")
    private String subCategoryName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="categoryId")
    private Category category;
Getter and Setter...
```

Controller Class as follow:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminProduct {

    private Path path;

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @Autowired
    private SubCategoryService subCategoryService;

    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @RequestMapping("/product/addProduct")
    public String addProduct(Model model){
        Product product = new Product();
        model.addAttribute("product", product);

        return "addProduct";
    }
    @ModelAttribute("subCategoryName")
    public Map<Integer, String> populateSubCategoryTypes() {
        Map<Integer, String> subCategoryNameMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        List<SubCategory> subCategoryList = this.subCategoryService.getAllSubCategroy();
        for (SubCategory subCategory : subCategoryList) {
            subCategoryNameMap.put(subCategory.getSubCategoryId(),subCategory.getSubCategoryName());
        }
        return sortByValue(subCategoryNameMap);
    }

    public <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> sortByValue(Map<K, V> map) {
        List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>(
                map.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
            public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2) {
                return (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
            }
        });

        Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : list) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

addProduct.jsp as follow:

```
 <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/product/addProduct"
                   method="post" commandName="product" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="category.categoryName">Category Name*</label>
            <form:select id="categoryName" path="category.categoryId" class="form-Control">
                <form:options items="${categoryName}" />
            </form:select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subCategoryList">SubCategory Name*</label>
            <form:select items="${subCategoryName}"  multiple="true" path="subCategoryList" class="form-Control" />
            </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        <a href="<c:url value="/admin/productInventory" />" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>

    </form:form>
```

When I run my codes, I get Category in Select Box and SubCategory in Multiple Select Box. But I when click submit button, I get null for SubCategory.

[image]

When I try to bind the subcategroy like below by adding itemvalue and itemid, I get error

```
<form:select items="${subCategoryName}" itemValue="subCategoryId" itemLabel="subCategoryName"  multiple="true" path="subCategoryList" class="form-Control" />
```

Error:

> org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'subCategoryId' of bean class [java.lang.Integer]: Bean
>   property 'subCategoryId' is not readable or has an invalid getter
>   method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of
>   the setter?
>
> I have already subCategoryId and subCategoryName property in my
>   SubCategory Model class.

Please help on how do I bind my data to get the select subcategory values.

Thank you so much.

Comment: could you show subcategory class ?

Comment: @shark, I have edited and add the subcategory model, please kindly help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

`<form:select items="${subCategoryName}" itemValue="subCategoryId" itemLabel="subCategoryName"  multiple="true" path="subCategoryList" class="form-Control" />`

with

`<form:select items="${subCategoryName}" multiple="true" path="subCategoryList" class="form-Control" />`

Note that the only change I am suggesting is removing the attributes `itemValue` and `itemLabel` from the `form:select` tag.

**Reason**:

From the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html), I am quoting the following:

> The items attribute is typically populated with a collection or array of item objects. itemValue and itemLabel simply refer to bean properties of those item objects, if specified; otherwise, the item objects themselves will be stringified. Alternatively, **you may specify a Map of items, in which case the map keys are interpreted as option values and the map values correspond to option labels. If itemValue and/or itemLabel happen to be specified as well, the item value property will apply to the map key and the item label property will apply to the map value.**

Refer to the text in bold in particular.

From your code sample, it seems that the model attribute 'subCategoryName' is a map of `Integer` keys and `String` values. So for a model attribute which is a map, as per the quote from the Spring docs above, map keys are automatically interpreted as option values and the corresponding map values are automatically interpreted as corresponding option labels. That's why you don't need to specify `itemValue` and `itemLabel`. But you are still specifying that. So as per the second line in the bold text in the quote above, whatever you specify in `itemValue` is interpreted as a bean property of the map keys - which is `integer` in your case. So that's why Spring tries to find the 'subCategoryId" field and its getter in `Integer` class and hence fails and throws the error.

Comment: Thank you VHS, I changed and tried like this code [<form:select items="${subCategoryName}" multiple="true" path="subCategoryList" class="form-Control" />] but when I click submit button for form post action, I debug and found that my subCategory has null value. May be the form doesn't know that Product model has SubCategory model. Please suggest.

Comment: Your form backing object is "product" and the the `path` attribute of your form:select tag is "subCategoryList". So the type of "subCateogorList" must be `List<Integer>`. But what you have is `List<Subcategory>'. You need to fix it.

Comment: I did same as Category Model as u can see in Product Model too, why Category works and SubCateogry does not work, as an example http://websystique.com/springmvc/springmvc-hibernate-many-to-many-example-annotation-using-join-table/
App_User has User_Profiles, I did almost same as the link post but its not working with me.

Comment: I checked the other code on that link. It works there because the model attribute "roles" is of type List<UserProfile> which matches with the path attribute type. But in your case, your model attribute is a map and your path attribute is a list of subcategories. Just change the type of subcategories to `List<Integer>'. It will start working.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I declared List<integer>subcategories with Transient annotation in my product model and find with query the above each subcategories value and set the SubCategory model list in my controller and finally persist in DB. It is working fine. Thank you so much.
PS: If I create a new model in which I declare Product,Category and SubCategory, may be I can also work the same as above.
I will invite you in my future questions if I faced with difficulties. :)

Comment: I want to do the same for an angular front end from a spring back end. would it be possible?